# Best way to test instance methods without running __init__

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've got a simple class that gets most of its arguments via init, which also runs a variety of private methods that do most of the work.  Output is available either through access to object variables or public methods.

Here's the problem - I'd like my unittest framework to directly call the private methods called by init with different data - without going through init.

What's the best way to do this?

So far, I've been refactoring these classes so that init does less and data is passed in separately.  This makes testing easy, but I think the usability of the class suffers a little.

EDIT: Example solution based on Ignacio's answer:

```
import types

class C(object):

   def __init__(self, number):
       new_number = self._foo(number)
       self._bar(new_number)

   def _foo(self, number):
       return number * 2

   def _bar(self, number):
       print number * 10

#--- normal execution - should print 160: -------
MyC = C(8)

#--- testing execution - should print 80 --------
MyC = object.__new__(C)
MyC._bar(8)
```

Comment: Also, I don't think you are trying to test [`classmethods`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod)—those wouldn't need to invoke `__init__` at all. If so, please update the title.

Comment: It seems bizarre and wrong to have your unittest framework test the object in a way that it's not going to be used.  If you just want to test the private members, initialize the object in your unittest as normal with init and then call them directly afterward to verify their individual behaviors.  Think of the horrible mystery you're creating for someone else when looking at your unittest to try and figure out why you went to so much trouble to not call init?!

Comment: In your example, the `_foo` and `_bar` methods don't make use of the instance (`self`)'s state, so they really should be static methods instead.  And if they were decorated with `@staticmethod` then you wouldn't need this crazy "create an object without initializing it" functionality.

Comment: If your unit-test requires intimate knowledge of your class initialization, then your class isn't - by definition - a unit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For new-style classes, call [`object.__new__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), passing the class as a parameter. For old-style classes, call [`types.InstanceType()`](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.InstanceType) passing the class as a parameter.

```
import types

class C(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print 'init'

class OldC:
  def __init__(self):
    print 'initOld'

c = object.__new__(C)
print c

oc = types.InstanceType(OldC)
print oc
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I've added a simplified version of what I'm doing with it in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Why does the usability of the class have to suffer? If all the `__init__` is doing is precomputing things so you can expose values as simple variables, change those variables into [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) and do the computation (potentially cached/memoized) in the getter. That way your `__init__` method is back to doing initialization only and testability is improved.

The downside to this approach is that it *might* be less performant, but probably not to a significant degree.

Comment: The    __init__    was actually running class functions, which eliminated the need for the user to run a separate function to run everything.  However, you're right - that could be handled by properties or a getter which wouldn't result in an extra call and would make things easier to test.  Thanks.